# HTML Homework Question - Flexbox - Beginner

Tags: html, flexbox

I am doing an exercise for my coding class and my code has failed like 30 times. Is there a syntax error? Am I missing something? I'm banging my head against my keyboard at this point so any help would be much appreciated. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUS5U.png :)

Comment: hi can you please post your problem with code snippet so i can help you to understand your problem thanks

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added the imgur to the post. :)

Comment: Buddy, it's image, code is much appreciated and also what is the problem

Comment: sure i will look into it

Comment: if you still have problem let me know

Comment: #info-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.info-card{
  border-left:10px solid black ;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

Comment: <div id="info-container">
 <div class="info-card">box1</div>
 <div class="info-card">box2</div>
 <div class="info-card">box3</div>
 <div class="info-card">box4</div>
</div>

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have put both suggestions into the grader and it still fails. I am wondering if there is something wrong on the grader's side, as I haven't had any problems with this assignment until now and the logic makes sense. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Please add code and mention what is the issue in code you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Added here just to make it more redable but it's actiually @Zubair Saif who added it in comments

```css
#info-container
{ 
  display: flex; justify-content: space-around; 
} 
#info-container > .info-card{ 
    border-left:10px solid black ; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    background: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div id="info-container">
  <div class="info-card"></div>
  <div class="info-card"></div>
  <div class="info-card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues that I identified in your code is listed below.

- Since your div elements dont have any content, you may have to set the height for the container.
- Also apply `flex: 1;` for `#info-container > .info-card`, that will help the child elements to grow equally inside the container.
- Since there is no child contents the `justify-content: space-around;` style in the parent don't have any functionality at present.

for

```css
#info-container {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: space-around; */

  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
#info-container > .info-card {
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-container">
  <div class="info-card"></div>
  <div class="info-card"></div>
  <div class="info-card"></div>
</div>
```